# Non-gtk desktop programs on Xubuntu 18.04 look terrible

Tags: xubuntu, gtk, snap, qt

I've been using xubuntu for the past few months and have been continuously struggling to understand why almost every time i install a new program, it looks like something from windows 95:

[image]

I included the file manager in the screenshot for an example of how I have configured the desktop appearance in the system settings.

- I've tried installing `qtconfig-qt4` but changing settings there has no effect.
- I installed `qt5ct` and it won't launch due to an error:

  > the qt_qpa_platformtheme environment variable is not set correctly
- I've tried setting the environment variable to `qt5ct` as suggested in some forums, and this also has no effect.
- I've also tried running `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct" qt5ct` which launches the Qt5 theme chooser. But choosing any theme does nothing other than change the theme of the theme chooser itself.
- I've added `export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk` to my `~/.bashrc` file and this does nothing either.

Additionally, while it may or may not be related, trying to change the theme using `gtk-theme-switch2` appears to work but then after closing the program i get the following error appear on-screen:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't "Most desktop programs on xubuntu look terrible" be better expressed as "Most **non-gtk** desktop programs on xubuntu look terrible"?

Comment: Hwt @DKBose, thanks for the suggestion, I didn't realise these were specifically non-gtk programs (actually i thought hexchat was gtk). I'll update the title as you've suggested though. :)

Comment: I think it's important to know which version of Xubuntu you use.

Comment: Also changes in `qtconfig-qt4` will not affect applications which are installed as snaps (could be the case for clementine which I see in your screenshot). Clementine is also available from standard repos and if installed via apt `qtconfig-qt4` should work.

Comment: @mook765 Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the title to reflect that.

Comment: @mook765, I've only installed things from the standard repos (at least, as far as I'm aware) using `apt`. I do have 3 other repos set up but they're just for the .net framework sdk, megasync, and steam.

Comment: snaps are also available via gnome-software, so maybe that's the way you installed them. Run `snap list` to see which snaps are installed on your system.

Comment: Oh there they are, I see Clementine and Hexchat, as well as a few other programs, there after running `snap list`. Thank you @mook765! Uninstalling the program then reinstalling using `apt` seems to have solved the problem. I remember, I did use the software centre to install these but I didn't realise that it worked any differently to using `apt` in the terminal. After reading a little about what snaps are, I suppose I should just stick to using `apt` from now on, at least until issues like this are fixed.

Comment: Don't forget to clean up your `~/.bashrc` and take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qtconfig-qt4` works for applications which are installed as `.deb`-packages and thus are integrated properly in the system.

Applications installed as snaps run in an isolated environment and you can't change their appearance with `qtconfig-qt4`.
I have `qtconfig-qt4` installed and the only change I made is the GUI-style in the `Appearance`-tab, changed from `default` to `GTK+`:

[image]

[image]

Clementine installed as a `.deb`-package looks like this:

[image]

But Clementine installed as a snap looks a bit ugly:

[image]

Clementine and Hexchat are available in both formats in `gnome-software`, as `.deb`-package as well as `snap`. When you install an application via `gnome-software`, scroll down to see the `Details` and take a look at the `Source` of the application.

[image]

[image]

[image]